# Transaction Fee of an Auction Smart Contract

Tags: contract-design, fees

I tried to write an auction smart contract recently and found an interesting question:

Let's assume there is an auction smart contract already deployed on Ethereum. There should be a *bid* function in this contract. When someone wants to attend the auction, he will invoke this function. This actually acts as submitting a transaction to blockchain. So he needs to pay some transaction fee.

In my view this feature sounds very terrible to potential participants. If I am a participant, I will worry that I might pay the transaction fee and lose in the auction finally. Then I get nothing but a financial loss.

Does anyone know how the real auction application deal with this problem? Can we possibly avoid the risk of losing money in the auction on Ethereum?

Comment: Did you take a look at [rollups](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/scaling/layer-2-rollups/)?

Comment: Yes It can reduce transaction fee. But I want to know how an auction smart contract attracts users. Even the fee is little, I think it will still be a problem for users. 

For example, intuitively, I can imagine two following solutions:

1. The transaction fee is very little before, so participants would like to attend the auction even they know they need to pay some fee.

2. Although the participant needs to pay transaction fee, the auctioneer promises that the transaction fee will be paid back to the participant when the auction ends. Then the participant has no worry.

Comment: I'm curious how a real auction application deals with this. Solution 1 or 2? Or some unknown solutions?

Comment: Some things in life need to be put in practice before a theoretical answer can be given. This auction idea of yours might be one of those things.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your kindly answer.